# Understanding how a private variable decorated with @property is used in Python

Tags: python, properties

Given below is my code snippet

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self,n1,n2):
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self._sum = None # WILL BE COMPUTED LATER ON

    @property
    def sum(self):
        if self._sum is None:
           self._sum = self.compute_sum()
        return self._sum

    def compute_sum(self):
        return(self.n1+self.n2)

test_obj = TestClass(5,6)

print(test_obj.sum)
```

This is just an example program illustrating the problem I'm facing.
I have a class with a private variable _sum in which I would like to hold the value of the two numbers n1 and n2.

The property sum can be used by the external world (so as to speak) to access the value of the sum without being able to modify its value. The reason why I have a private variable _sum is so that the value is computed once and stored for subsequent fetches.

Just having @property would compute the value every single time someone tries to access the value of sum through an instance and I would like to avoid this given 
the performance impact (keep in mind, this is just an example to illustrate the actual problem that I'm facing)

Given my requirement to be able to sum to all external objects to use but at the same time not have it be computed every time it's called, is my implementation, design wise, correct ?

It's also quite interesting that the value of _sum is computed even before the function is called, at least my IDE was able to do that, not sure how.

In the screenshot seen below, we're on line 9 and compute_sum() hasn't been called, yet the value has already been computed. How come ?

[image]

Comment: As currently written, the pre-computed sum isn't recalculated if `n1` or `n2` changes. Either compute the sum on-demand each time, or make `n1` and `n2` properties as well which update the sum if either value changes.

Comment: Your IDE appears to have accessed the attribute to show the `self` variables reference.

Comment: When your debugger fetched the value for `self.sum` it was calculated.  Introspection caused a side-effect.  Introspecting introspection required introspection.

Comment: `self._sum` is set `None` in the initializer of your class, so as soon as you create `testobj` the `testobj._sum` is `None`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Is there anyway I can use the debugger without actually making it affect the execution/fetch in this way ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar: I'm not sure why PyCharm is actually doing that, but I can't find any setting for it. Presumably this *is* PyCharm?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes :(

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't make much sense to me. `_sum` is `None`, but `sum` is 11. Have you perhaps made a typo before and forgot to save the corrected file? I don't have PyCharm installed to verify what happens to properties.

Comment: At any rate, the *code you posted* works fine. If your debugger is showing you `sum` set to `11` and *at the same time* showing you `_sum` set to `None`, then that is either a bug in the debugger, or you haven't shown us the actual code that might have been run by the interpreter before you altered it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It seems likely that PyCharm accessed `_sum`, found `None`, accessed `sum`, found `11`, and then didn't bother to go back and check `_sum` again.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: it doesn't add up however. If `self.sum` produced 11 then it has been computed and `self._sum` has been assigned already. Yet the same area of the screenshot clearly shows `_sum` still being `None`.

Comment: @user2357112: also a possibility, I guess. Still, I'd consider that a bug in PyCharm then, if the UI can't monitor variables properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  At that breakpoint where it introspects `self` first it grabs `self._sum` which is `None`, then `self.n1` which is `5`, then `self.n2` which is `6`, then it grabs `self.sum` which prompts a method call.  After that `self._sum` will be `11`, but the debugger already introspected it and missed the change.

Comment: I've updated  the screenshot with what I'm observing now, same code but now _sum has been computed

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: makes sense, pity that PyCharm can't be told to keep its mitts off property descriptors.

Comment: In your new screenshot the breakpoint is set earlier at line 18 so `self` is  introspected on that line.  Now when it gets to line 9 it's already visited `.sum` in a prior introspection.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: bingo, bug report confirms the hypothesis: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-13006